# python shell not able to find sqlite table

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I have created a sqlite table using sqlite browser. I have added one row too. When I connect to the table through terminal, I am able to find the table as well as row.

However, I am trying to connect to table through python as I have lots of rows to be inserted. Even though I wrote a python program, I tried to connect and insert the row through shell.

```
import sqlite3
import os
home=os.environ['HOME']
conn=sqlite3.connect(home+'/AndroidStudioProjects/TableTopicPractice/database/dbTableTopic')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
print cur.rowcount
```

The last statement printed -1. When I tried to query the specific table that I created, the result was same. Both the query I tried in sqlite browser and it works.

Please note sqlite3 is installed in my system. I used the following tutorial as guide.

> http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/

Where am I going wrong? What do I need to correct?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The file name is wrong.

Comment: @Cl I have used the same file name to connect through terminal and I am.able to connect.